# Java keytool throws OutOfMemoryError during -list

Tags: java, out-of-memory, keytool

I am trying to use `keytool` on a Windows System which is a part of my JDK1.8 install. I got an `OutOfMemoryError`. I was wondering if there is an option to increase the heap size like `-Xmx` used with the JVM. I tried that but the -X option was not recognized.

Here is the command I used:

```
keytool -list -keystore c:\myfolder\myp12file.p12 -storetype PKCS12
```

Just a note, I was able to use the windows "certutil -dump" to dump the contents of the keystore, which is similar to `keytool -list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to give Java options to `keytool` using the [`-J` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#sthref127).

To set the `MaxMetaspaceSize` to `128m` for example:

```
keytool -J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -list -keystore c:\myfolder\myp12file.p12 -storetype PKCS12
```

Comment: Last sentence is not correct: `-Xmx` still sets maximum heap size in Java 8. PermGen/Metaspace is completely different from heap space. Also, the default size for class meta data is _unlimited_ (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). With `MaxMetaspaceSize=128m` you are only restricting a previously unrestricted size.